# Correct way of getting user ip address

Tags: python, django

I got this code from stack overflow answers. Getting user ip address

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for =request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip= x_forwarded_for.split(",")[0]
    else:
        ip=request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR',None)
    return ip
```

This works well when i am running my webapp on local environment,but when i launched the website online, it does not get the right ip address allocated to me by ISP. And my ip the code gets keep on changing when ever i reload .
What is the correct way to go about solving this problem thank you

Comment: Your ISP probably has a proxy, that's the address the website sees.

Comment: ...or a carrier grade NAT, which is unlucky rather common nowadays.